# iOS CPU_FATAL 0% in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibackgroundtask

I'm working on background audio playing for my app. But some of users warned me about one strange bug. After 1 hour or more playing in background the app is killed by iOS and you need to launch it again.

Mostly it happens with bad internet connection, when the app has have to create background task very often and use it until enough data will be downloaded to start playback again.

I know about time limit for background tasks and it's not an issue. Here is a part of crash log from user's device:

[image]
Most important lines:

```
Exception Type: EXC_RESOURCE
Exception Subtype: CPU_FATAL
Exception Message: (Limit 80%) Observed 0% over 60 sec
Triggered by Thread: 0
```

The most strange is the third line. Why is it an exception, if 0% is below limit of 80%?

By symbolicating stack trace of the Thread 0 (it's main thread), I found that it happened on method `- [NSFileManager fileExistsAtPath:]`. Previously it happened on method `+ [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:]`. So what could freeze access to the file system in background on iOS?

Also:

- It happens when the app tries to set image on a lock screen.
- Images are stored in Cache folder.

Answer (score 0):

From Apple docs:

You can use any of the system audio frameworks to work with background audio content, and the process for using those frameworks is unchanged. (For video playback over AirPlay, you can use the Media Player or AV Foundation framework to present your video.) Because your app is not suspended while playing media files, callbacks operate normally while your app is in the background. In your callbacks, though, you should do only the work necessary to provide data for playback. For example, a streaming audio app would need to download the music stream data from its server and push the current audio samples out for playback. Apps should not perform any extraneous tasks that are unrelated to playback.

So if you do things like downloading images and saving them etc, you break this rule.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but first: images are already downloaded. Second: it happens when I try to set cover art on lock screen. Apple provides this API and it's definitely related to the background playback (the app tries to set cover art of current playing track).